# php error log save date-wise

Tags: php, apache, error-logging

We want to monitor all php errors. We can check all errors with error_log file.
Error logs files become so heavy.

So it is very difficult to check errors in error_log file.

Could it possible to write php error_log file on date-wise example '19-05_2015_error.log'

or we can write error like "fetal.log" "notice.log"

Comment: What role does the Apache tag play in this question? Are you using PHP's `error_log` feature or relying on Apache logging?

Comment: we are on relying on apache logging

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely do it in PHP. A popular logging library is [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog).

Answer (score 1):

You can change the PHP config at beginning of your application, create the log file dynamically.

```
<?php

function logByDate(){
    $sPath = '/logs/application/PhpError_' . date('Y-m-d') . '.log';
    ini_set('error_log', $sPath);
}

// To validate only, it is not necessary
echo 'Actual log ' . ini_get('error_log') . PHP_EOL; 

logByDate(); //Call it at beginning

// To validate only, it is not necessary
echo 'Validate new log ' . ini_get('error_log') . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get logs in daily format (19-05_2015_error.log) you can use [logrotate](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-linux-log-files-with-logrotate/) if you're on a UNIX stack (but it' a bit more complicated if you're on a [Windows stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355737/apache-rotate-access-and-error-logs-windows/355857#355857)).
There are some useful hints on controlling duplication and [suppressing error messages](https://perishablepress.com/advanced-php-error-handling-via-htaccess/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, [the mod_log_config module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_log_config.html) does not accept variables for file names so that excludes the most straightforward possibility. Apache-based solutions you can actually use include basically:

- Send [logs to a script](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/logs.html#piped) and let the script choose the file name.
- Good old [log rotation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/logs.html#rotation).

Said that, I think PHP has pretty good built-in logging. You can do exactly what you are asking for with the [`error_log()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) (together with e.g. [`date('Y-m-d')`](http://php.net/date)). You can even define a different file for different error types. Sure, that will not capture errors that prevent PHP code from running (such as parse errors, request time-outs...) but you can set the [`error_log` directive](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) as fallback mechanism—these situations should be rare enough to keep the log file manageable.

One more thought: make sure your development box has full error reporting enabled (many devs use third-party bundles with default settings and happily write buggy code). It isn't normal to have so many logged errors in a production server.